# Settings the context of 'this' in IIFE

Tags: javascript

I want to bind the 'this' context of the following code to the `Collection` prototype object, but right now it refers to the window object instead.

So far I have tried to wrap the function definition as a IIFE, but this doesn't change the context.

My code

```
Mongo.Collection.prototype.bulk = (function(){
  var context = this; <------- should refer to the prototype's context and not the object 'bulk'

  return {
    insert: function(documents, options) {

    },
    update: function() {

    },
    upsert: function() {

    }
  };
})();
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: No need for an IIFE here. `prototype.bulk = function() { var context = this; }`

Comment: yes, but I want to 'namespace' the insert, update and upsert operations under the bulk object. when I just define bulk as a function, i cannot call `SomeCollection.bulk.insert()`

Comment: Do you want this to refer to Mongo.Collection. prototype or to the Mongo.collection instance?

Answer (score 1):

RGraham's comment is the correct answer.
There's no need for the IIFE. You can just do a plain `prototype.fn = function() { var context = this; }`

But if (for whatever reason) you can't do that... then you can pass whatever you want to use as the `context` as a parameter to the IIFE:

```
Mongo.Collection.prototype.bulk = (function(context){
  return {
    insert: function(documents, options) {

    },
    update: function() {

    },
    upsert: function() {

    }
  };
})(Mongo.Collection.prototype);
```

Comment: I tried this, but the context still refers to the window

Comment: That's very odd... can you share the whole code somewhere? _Do note that you have to pass Mongo.Collection.prototype as a parameter to the IIFE in the **last line** of the code_

Comment: In this snippet: `this` refers to the window and `context` refers to `Mongo.Collection.prototype`.

Comment: I know, but you don't even need to use `this` right? I think that's what the OP wanted. A way to refer to the prototype in the function. It's not a requisite that `this` be referred. See the second line in his code, it says `var context = this; <------- should refer to the prototype's context and not the object 'bulk'`. That's what this answer is doing. It's assigning **what should be `this` to the context object**